# Is it necessary to delete last migration and then add migration with same name?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have a class in EF and I want to change some 'properties' or add new 'properties' in it. Then do an 'add-migration' and 'update-database'. so I should to delete last migration before I 'add-migration' or not?

Answer (score 0):

Migrations are cumulative, so no, you don't usually delete the old ones. I will occasionally "roll up" migrations before I do a production deploy. See this link for the process. http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/#at_pco=smlwn-1.0&at_si=54ad5c7b61c48943&at_ab=per-12&at_pos=0&at_tot=1

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already run the last migration to the DB and you have modified the model, then yes, you have to delete the last migration and create a new one (or run Add-Migration with the same name and the switch -Force to overwrite it).

But, if you have already run the last migration (so after doing Add-Migration you have done Update-database), then what you have to do is add a new migration in order to do an incremental change.